# Tomcat8 hangs up while deploying

Tags: java, deployment, spring-boot, war, tomcat8

**FOLLOWING IS THE UNSTABLE VERSION LOG :**

```
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    29-Feb-2016 12:51:28.535 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    29-Feb-2016 12:51:28.559 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2950 ms
    29-Feb-2016 12:51:28.662 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
    29-Feb-2016 12:51:28.663 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
    29-Feb-2016 12:51:28.843 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT.war
```

**FOLLOWING IS THE UNSTABLE VERSION LOG WITH JSTACK DUMP:**

```
01-Mar-2016 06:17:03.508 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
01-Mar-2016 06:17:03.508 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
01-Mar-2016 06:17:03.707 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT.war
2016-03-01 06:21:20
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.31-b07 mixed mode):

"localhost-startStop-1" #17 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f924c012800 nid=0x854 runnable [0x00007f9250a19000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
    at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:849)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2013)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2022)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1964)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1915)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1158)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:780)
    - locked <0x00000000e32d0768> (a org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    - locked <0x00000000e32d26b8> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    - locked <0x00000000e32d26b8> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1812)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Catalina-startStop-1" #16 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9268482000 nid=0x851 waiting on condition [0x00007f9250b1e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e31001e0> (a java.util.concurrent.FutureTask)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:400)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:286)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:394)
    - locked <0x00000000e3100068> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:339)
    - locked <0x00000000e3100068> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:933)
    - locked <0x00000000e3100068> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    - locked <0x00000000e3100068> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    - locked <0x00000000e3100068> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-2" #15 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9268472800 nid=0x84c runnable [0x00007f9250c20000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x00000000e3100528> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000000e3100538> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000e31004e0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller.run(NioBlockingSelector.java:342)

"NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-1" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9268463800 nid=0x84b runnable [0x00007f9250d21000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x00000000e31005d8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000000e31005e8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000e3100590> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller.run(NioBlockingSelector.java:342)

"GC Daemon" #13 daemon prio=2 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f92683b4000 nid=0x83a in Object.wait() [0x00007f9251493000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000e31005f8> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)
    at sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run(GC.java:117)
    - locked <0x00000000e31005f8> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)

"AsyncFileHandlerWriter-99747242" #12 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f926810f800 nid=0x833 waiting on condition [0x00007f9251df5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e2c4d648> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:522)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:684)
    at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler$LoggerThread.run(AsyncFileHandler.java:145)

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f92680bc800 nid=0x822 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread1" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f92680b7800 nid=0x7d4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f92680b5000 nid=0x6b8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"JDWP Event Helper Thread" #6 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f92680b3000 nid=0x6b6 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" #5 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f92680af800 nid=0x6b2 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f92680a0800 nid=0x6ad waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9268074800 nid=0x67a in Object.wait() [0x00007f9252801000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000e2c4e750> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
    - locked <0x00000000e2c4e750> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:158)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9268072800 nid=0x677 in Object.wait() [0x00007f9252902000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000e2c4e790> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
    - locked <0x00000000e2c4e790> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f926800b800 nid=0x5eb waiting on condition [0x00007f926fd14000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e3100400> (a java.util.concurrent.FutureTask)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    - locked <0x00000000e3100678> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    - locked <0x00000000e3100678> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    - locked <0x00000000e3100678> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    - locked <0x00000000e3100678> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    - locked <0x00000000e2c4e7d0> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    - locked <0x00000000e2c4e818> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    - locked <0x00000000e2c4e828> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f926806d800 nid=0x668 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f92680bf800 nid=0x823 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 2015

Heap
 def new generation   total 16640K, used 4482K [0x00000000d4000000, 0x00000000d5200000, 0x00000000e2aa0000)
  eden space 14848K,  30% used [0x00000000d4000000, 0x00000000d445c1d0, 0x00000000d4e80000)
  from space 1792K,   0% used [0x00000000d5040000, 0x00000000d50446c8, 0x00000000d5200000)
  to   space 1792K,   0% used [0x00000000d4e80000, 0x00000000d4e80000, 0x00000000d5040000)
 tenured generation   total 36864K, used 9565K [0x00000000e2aa0000, 0x00000000e4ea0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 36864K,  25% used [0x00000000e2aa0000, 0x00000000e33f7508, 0x00000000e33f7600, 0x00000000e4ea0000)
 Metaspace       used 13333K, capacity 13508K, committed 13568K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1456K, capacity 1525K, committed 1536K, reserved 1048576K
```

**FOLLOWING IS THE STABLE VERSION LOG :**

```
25-Feb-2016 11:14:45.177 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
25-Feb-2016 11:14:45.742 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Feb-2016 11:14:45.788 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
25-Feb-2016 11:14:45.806 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
25-Feb-2016 11:14:45.808 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
25-Feb-2016 11:14:45.814 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1996 ms
25-Feb-2016 11:14:45.897 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
25-Feb-2016 11:14:45.897 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
25-Feb-2016 11:14:45.993 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT.war
25-Feb-2016 11:14:46.196 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand An expanded directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT] was found with a last modified time that did not match the associated WAR. It will be deleted.
25-Feb-2016 11:15:00.462 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.1.RELEASE)
```

Question :  Tomcat8 does not move forward once it starts deploying the WAR file. WAR File is located in and has the appropriate permissions:

```
/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT.WAR
```

I can not figure out the reason why it is getting blocked and does not move forward. I newbie. I tried changing user permissions and groups but no luck.

Comment: Can you take a thread dump while it's blocked and share the output? You can use `jvisualvm` or `kill -3 <pid>` to produce one.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I have edited the question like you asked. I hope i have added the right logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the build is SUCCESSFUL and If its not an entropy issue. 
It is highly possible that it is an issue related to tomcat.

Check tomcat8 logs :

```
/usr/share/tomcat8/logs/tomcat.initd.logs
```

It will help to figure out where the problem lies. I just used

```
sudo adduser -d tomcat tomcat
```

: Adding a user and a home directory. `useradd` is not recommended and activate the account with

```
sudo passwd tomcat
```

and then start the tomcat8 installation process.